# Re open the review and converter to Swift 2.0-Xcode 7

Tags: swift2, xcode7, xcode7-beta6

I open my project (swift 1.2) by Xcode 7, and the Xcode suggestion to me convert to Swift 2.0. But I canceled it, now I want to open the review and converter of Xcode 7. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the answer you are looking for `To Latest Swift Syntax` at the latest menu.

[image]